# Unable to deploy Vuejs project to AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, vue.js, vuejs2, amazon-ecs

My code was running properly, but when I tried to deploy the last version of my code, the task in ECS started showing that the status is "stopped", and this error appeared:

```
starting container process caused "exec: \"http-server\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Nothing was changed in any of the Docker files, the newest version of the code contains some basic changes in the html and JS files.

Also when trying to deploy an old version of the code that was deployed properly in the past I'm still getting the same error

The frontend docker file:

```
FROM node:6-alpine

# ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN npm install -g http-server

EXPOSE 8080

COPY ./package.json /src/
COPY ./npm-shrinkwrap.json /src/

WORKDIR /src

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD ["http-server", "dist/"]
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code... can you add your Dockerfile and (if possible) some info about how you deploy your code?

Comment: did you ship an alpine version by any chance ?

Comment: Please post the content of the dockerfile in your question.

Comment: added the docker file to the question. Thanks for the quick responses

Comment: Take ECS out of the equation -- do you get the same error if you run the Docker container locally?

Comment: runs properly when I run the container locally

Comment: To eliminate the obvious: are you sure you're running the same image in your local environment and in ECS? How do you publish the image and update the ECS service? (I'd extend your question with some deployment process details as suggested initially).

Comment: I have a jenkins job that builds the image 
the service is connected to that and I deploy a new task by clicking on update at the top right corner (all the parameters weren't changed) I get a message that says the deployment finished
and then the task fails with the "http-server" error